# Как выводить шапку в MVC (php)?

Tags: php, ооп, mvc, header

Начал изучение недавно, возник вопрос допустим как выводить меню на сайте через базу и данные пользователя допустим приветствие "привет, Андрей". Если шапка лежит в отдельном файле и везде данные одинаковые выводить то шапку надо вывести в отдельный файл. Каждый раз для каждого контроллера в модели делать новый запрос думаю не правильно.

Comment: мне интересен вывод из базы не меняющейся инфы чтобы постоянно не делать запрос в новой модели контроллера

Comment: Ну будет допустим `MenuWidget` который является наследником от какого-либо `BaseController` который будет отвечать за меню и не завит от того, что прописано в URL..... а в `layout` будет специально отведенное место, где данная инфа будет выводиться..... о том что такое виджет и как работают можно посмотреть на примере например популярного фреймворка `yii2`

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы много раз в базу не обращаться, можно использовать метод кеширования.

Например вот так:

1) Есть основной шаблон вьюшки, которая для вызова хеадера использует функцию `get_header($user)`;

2) Есть шаблон хеадера, например, который генерится функцией `build_header()`:

```
<header>
  <div class="logo-block">
    <a href="/" class="logo">My Site</a>
    <span class="phone">Phone: <b>+7(999)555-55-55</b></span>
  </div>
  <div class="user-block">
    Hello, {username}! <a href="#">Log out</a>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel">
    <img src="/...">
    <img src="/...">
    <img src="/...">
    <img src="/...">
    ...
  </div>
</header>
```

В этом шаблоне номер телефона и карусель загружаются по каким-то значениям из базы.

3) Функция get_header($user):

```
// пример массива $user = array('username'=>'Вася');
function get_header($user) {
  $header = '';
  $file = 'header.tmp';
  if (file_exists($file)) {
    if ((time()-filemtime($file))>600) { //если кеш старше 10 минут, то будем генерить новый
      $header = file_get_contents($file);
    }
  }
  if (empty($header)) {
    $header = build_header();
    $h = fopen($file, 'w');
    fwrite($h, $header);
    fclose($h);
  }
  $sarr = $rarr = array();
  foreach($user as $key => $value) {
    $sarr[] = '{'.$key.'}';
    $rarr[] = $value;
  }
  $header = str_replace($sarr, $rarr, $header);
  return $header; // или print $header; - по желанию
}
```

4) А сам этот массив $user, который передается в get_header() можно брать, например, из $_COOKIE["USER"], в которую предварительно его сохранить.

Пример, конечно, не идеальный. Но в этом случае получится снять нагрузку на сервер.

Я бы посоветовал использовать шаблонизатор смарти, там уже есть готовые решения с кешированием. Либо можете еще что-то поискать, я помню, что видел далеко не 1-2 варианта.

Comment: Кэширование к этому вопросу ну вообще никаким боком.

Comment: @Ипатьев вы о чем? Предложенный мной метод дает возможность сохранить определенный блок кода (в примере header) в файл при первом выводе, а затем повторно уже не строить его, а подгружать из файла (читай из кеша).

Comment: Кстати, информации о кешировании в интернете есть достаточно. Вот один из ресурсов https://htmlweb.ru/php/php_cache.php